# Equation for Standard Error

Tags: r, lm

All,

I am trying to figure out the formula that computes the std.error for the factors for the below regression and how to compute that using the mean and sd functions. (std.error=2.015). Please help.

Thanks.
Rik

```
k=5;n=4;
s1=4;s2=8;mu1=75
factor1=as.factor(rep(1:k,n))
sim1=rep(rnorm(k,mu1,s2),n)
sim2=rep(rnorm(k*n,0,s1))
sim=sim1+sim2
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
lm1=lm(sim~factor1)
> summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = sim ~ factor1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.2234 -2.3561  0.7269  2.9855  7.9084 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   79.513      1.007  78.923  < 2e-16 ***
factor11       6.216      2.015   3.085 0.007545 ** 
factor12      -1.051      2.015  -0.522 0.609399    
factor13       9.101      2.015   4.517 0.000409 ***
factor14      -4.543      2.015  -2.255 0.039534 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.506 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7575,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6928 
F-statistic: 11.71 on 4 and 15 DF,  p-value: 0.0001624
```

Comment: you can look at the code to see how it is calculated  in  R:  see `summary.lm`

Comment: See CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any of these to get the std error:

```
sqrt(sum(resid(lm1)^2)/(length(factor1) - nlevels(factor1)))

sqrt(deviance(lm1)/(length(factor1) - nlevels(factor1)))

summary.lm(lm1)$sigma

library(broom); glance(lm1)$sigma
```

If you want the std error of the coefficients then if `se` is any of the above then:

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(lm1)))

se * sqrt(diag(solve(crossprod(model.matrix(lm1)))))

se * sqrt(diag(summary.lm(lm1)$cov))

coef(summary(lm1))[, 2]

library(broom); tidy(lm1)$std.error
```

Note that (1) since the question did not use `set.seed` to set the random number generator to a known state the data is not reproducible and (2) As mentioned in the comments `summary.lm` source code will give the details of how it does it which may not be precisely the same as we showed here but would be equivalent except for numerical error.

Comment: I think the OP was looking for the standard error of the parameters, not the residual standard deviation ...